# Missing perl on appveyor windows?

Tags: appveyor

Since about 2 days we have problems running our tests with appveyor on windows systems.
We get the error message:

```
(CustomBuild target) -> 
  CUSTOMBUILD : error : Problems running bibtex. Verify that the command 'perl --version' works from the command line. Exit code: 2
```

We installed the bibtex.
It concerns (at least) the "VSVERSION=15 2017" and VSVERSION=14 2015" for 32 and 64 bit

Did anything change on the Windows machines regarding perl?

Comment: Last updated of Windows images was on Nov 8: https://www.appveyor.com/updates/2019/11/08/. Could it be some of your external dependencies that changed overnight?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of in case of a correct run and a wrong run both log files have in the beginning: "perl --version
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)"

Comment: Further investigations (after a long time) lead to MiKTeX, looks like the `bibtex.exe` is missing. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524088/installing-miktex-missing-executables-when-using-miktexsetup and a github issue reference: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/443. A followup question on this question has been posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59730937/continue-after-a-failing-command-in-appveyor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was not a missing `perl` executable but an executable (`bibtex`) called from the used perl script.
The `bibtex` executable was not provided by MiKTeX anymore resulting in this, misleading, resulting error.

The MiKTeX problem has been solved by means of: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/443 by declaring the package miktex-misc an essential package (again).