# Continue after a failing command in appveyor

Tags: appveyor

In appveyor I use the statement:
`- initexmf --admin --force --mklinks`
but due to a problem it gives the message:

```
initexmf --admin --force --mklinks
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:
  Script configuration file not found.
The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
  C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_admin.log
The system cannot find the path specified.
Command exited with code 1
```

due to the error code the process terminates and I cannot `type` the `C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_admin.log` anymore, so a bit hard to debug ...

**questions**:

- How to continue after an error
- How to stop after the outputting the file (`exit 1` ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a script on failure use `on_failure` section, for example to push `initexmf_admin.log` to artifacts:

```
on_failure:
- appveyor PushArtifact C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_admin.log
```